# Fortigate 60D - Empty log and report

Tags: firewall, logging, fortinet, fortigate, report

Environment:

- Fortigate 60D
- Forti OS 5.0

I can not see any log or report in the firewall. I have already activated forticloud and I recieve empty reports.
Is there something that we have to activate in the firewall?